# How to remove unused methods in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

For example, I have two projects sharing some functions, let's say them A and B. So I create another library project C, containing the public code.
I put the common code in a class, but in the class, not all the methods are used in both projects.
Some of them are only used in A, some only used in B and the rest are used in both of them.

Now, after compiling, I got A.exe, B.exe and C.dll. What I want is:

1. I don't want the dll, just want A.exe and B.exe
2. I don't want methods only used in A.exe appears in B.exe, and vice versa.

Merging the dll and exe can solve the problem 1, but how about 2?

Comment: Each project is going to create their own output.  (dll, exe, etc) So getting rid of c's dll seems unlikely.  With a and b, if you dont want to expose methods, then make them private or proctected.

Comment: I think this is not good idea, but you can put the A methods using internal class in project A, put the B methods in project B, and put common methods in project A then in project B add project A reference.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a static library, not a DLL.

If C were a static library, then when you compile A (with the compiler set to drop unused stuff), A's exe will have all code required by A taken from the static library C and put directly into the exe.  The same would go for B.

But that's not how DLLs work.

With a DLL, A is getting the "services" of some code from C, but since the code lives in C, A has no control over what code is in C.

As @RobertMoskal points out, there are answers out there with tools that do what you want.  I just wanted to clarify that your intent is counter to the design of Dlls although it can be done with the tools mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: BTW, all of that said, it's worth noting that .NET does not have static libraries by design.  See this for a discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835761/why-does-c-sharp-not-have-c-style-static-libraries

Comment: I have thought a alternative. I can add the source files in C to A and B as link, then I can use the classes and methods in A and B without creating a dll. Now the question is can the compile remove the methods not used in the generated exe? I think my situation is different as I have the source code of the libraries.

Comment: Using this solution, i.e., a link, when you have the compiler set to optimize (i.e. Release configuration), it may well discard unused code.  You'd have to test it out.