# Building a static library in a C# application

Tags: c#, c++, c, static-libraries

In my [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) application, I have to use some C code which is generated from TargetLink model. For this, in my solution I have added the C Code to a VC++ project and am building it into a static library. I have added another VC++ project with a C++ class to interface between C# and C(Static Library) and building it to a dll.

I have a new requirement in which the user will browse to the location of the C Code as the code may change periodically. The application has to use this code. I want to build a dll with the C++ class and the C Code.

[image]

What I have tried so far is parsing the .vcxproj file and changed the path of the C Files to the new location. I find this complicated and am looking for a better way to do this.

Comment: Hard links may help you. You reference source from a known fixed location but it's an hard link you change as they wish to _true_ source code location (of course if included files won't change, just their location).

Comment: What? Where does the c# app come into all this? Question is unclear

Comment: Please check this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835761/why-does-c-sharp-not-have-c-style-static-libraries

Answer (score 0):

Do you use MS Visual Studio? Then if you write a PreBuild command for the C++ project which overwrites the source files if newer version exists in the user's location, it doesn't solve your problem?

Comment: When I release the executable. Customer won't have VS. He want to build the C code when new C code is available. So I need to provide it as a feature in my application.

Comment: @Abhishek So, if I understand correctly you have a C# application that uses a C++ DLL which links a static C library. The user should be able to choose updated C source files location and then your C++ DLL should automagically starts using these updated code instead the one that was used when it was been compiled?

Comment: @codroipo: Yes. Exactly

Comment: @Abhishek this is quite hard/impossible(and unreliable). The user should have MS VC++ compiler installed, then you should call VC++ compiler with correct arguments to compile static library, then, in a separate program, because the DLL is currently used by the process so it cannot be replaced, you have to call VC++ compiler with correct arguments to rebuild the C++ DLL linking to the new build of the static library(so you have also to distribute C++ DLL source); replace the DLL and restart your program. All this keeping your fingers crossed.

Comment: @Abhishek An acceptable alternative would be to use a C DLL instead of a static library and dynamically load it in your C++ wrapper. When someone want the C code to change, he/she edit it, rebuild the DLL and replace it.